# Hide/Show button for HTML email

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-mail

I am generating an HTML email using a java program and need a Hide/Show button for some queries, 
What would be an ideal approach for this?, shd i call a javascript from java program to do the same?.

I have a javascript module to do the show/hide feature but not sure how to integrate this to a java program.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is completely independent from any server-side framework or language, such as Java.

If you want to show or hide an HTML element on a page, try the following JS code:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'none';
```

And then, when you generate the HTML email using Java, include the queries you want to hide in a `<div>` with a specified ID.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your generated html tags and use css to control the visibility and other styling.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .hid {display: none;}
</stle>

<div class='query1 hid'>...</div>
<div class='query2'>...</div>
<div class='query1 hid'>...</div>
```

Then update your javascript to manipulate the class attribute.

```
//in jQuery...
$("btn1").click(function() {
    $(".query2").addClass("hid");
    $(".query1").removeClass("hid");
});
```